# Are there inconsistencies between Cypress tool and running them from the terminal?

Tags: cypress

i'm evaluating Cypress (Version 3.4.1), and running into inconsistencies between running the same tests from the cypress tool and running them from the terminal, i'm using the same browser in both cases (Electron 61). Anyone experienced this? (failing test from the terminal, but same test runs smoothly from the Cypress tool)

Comment: I suggest that you describe what's the failure you're seeing, and if you can, create a simplified repro. Running Cypress from the terminal typically saves videos of the browser running the tests which can help your determine what happened.

Comment: It means that you need to fix the part which produces the flakiness in the integration tests

Comment: I also found this to be the case, developed the specs in the GUI and they started failing in when using cypress-run. Fixed by running `--headed`. Presume that headless does a lot less with CSS (as also found with Jest / JSDom). My app uses CSS for a lot more than colors and padding, so any test that just addresses JS logic is inadequate for me.

Answer (score 0):

The interactive test runner can be flakey, but I do not see the same issues when I run without the interactive test runner. I wouldn't worry about the test failing in the interactive test runner if it passes when you refresh the page, or passes when run via command line. Use the browser refresh button not the interactive test runner refresh button.

Note: cypress is pretty heavy on your resources. I noticed I have intermittent failures when doing a screen share.

Answer (score 0):

While running Cypress rest from command, I found that the test finishes with All specs passed, but yet it didn't complete the full iterations (last one is to save form in db, didn't happen). 
I didn't know why? I tried to change the Cypress code but with no result.
I decided to check the recorded video after test finishes from terminal so I enabled video recording and TARAA!! Test finished correctly. Once I disable video recording It fails.